# find and replace shell script to create a usable csv file

Tags: shell, batch-file, sh

I have a big problem. I have taken many measurements with a measuring program. I get several * .SP8 files which are nothing more than text files. With Automator I could rename all in *.csv.

I now need a script that clears out my first 29 rows of the content. Then the script must replace all spaces with a semicolon.

The script must find all csv-files in a specified folder within all subfolders.

Ideally it would find the first space in one line and replaces it with a semicolon and clears the rest in the line.

The File looks like:

```
Test
22.01.2016
..
Tester
20160122_BM_BLANK

User

20160122_BM_BLANK
Text
@@6.000 5.350   1.000   12.000  8.500   1020.000    60.000  940.000 4.773   0.000   1.500   14.800  0.000   100.000 0.000   9.000   0
@@SWB 533 [blank]
blank
SK 999100.10
no


100Nm.SEN
100 Nm 
Last 01/2013
SN: "HBM,Spider8-55/01,08231,P32"






1200
7200
0   -0.015238   0   -0.0465 0
0   -0.015238   0   -0.0465 0.000833
0   -0.025  0   -0.0465 0.001667
... following 6000 lines of code like this ...
384.5   -0.025  0   -0.0465 5.9975
384.5   -0.025  0   -0.0465 5.998333
384.5   -0.025  0   -0.0465 5.999166

End
```

This should be turned into this:

```
0;-0.015238
0;-0.015238
0;-0.025
... following 6000 lines of code like this ...
384.5;-0.025
384.5;-0.025
384.5;-0.025
```

The target is to load this in EXCEL and create a graph

Comment: `for` to find all files, `for /f` to process them (`skip` to skip the first n lines, `tokens` to get what you want), `echo` to print. Give it a try. We will help you, but we won't do your work. See [for /?](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) for details.

Comment: thank you - i'll give it a try

Comment: [shell] and [sh] imply 'nix, but [batch-file] and Excel imply Windows batch file - Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), a pure script utility (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward:

```
@echo off
pushd "yourRootPath"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'findstr /smc:" " *.csv'
) do call jrepl " +" ";" /a /jbegln "skip=(ln<30)" /f "%%F" /o -
popd
```

The FINDSTR command finds and lists all .CSV files that contain a space (already converted files will no longer have a space).

The FOR /F command iterates each resultant file.

JREPL.BAT does the rest

- The search/replace replaces each run of consecutive spaces with a single `;`
- `/a` Only altered lines are printed
- `/jbegln ...` ignores the first 29 lines
- `/f "%%F"` Specifies the source file
- `/o -` Overwrites the original file with the result

### Update 2018/10/03

Starting with JREPL v4.0, the first 29 lines can be ignored via the `/EXC` option instead of using user supplied JScript via the `/JBEGLN` option.

```
) do call jrepl " +" ";" /a /exc 1:29 /f "%%F" /o -
```

Also, I just realized the OP wanted to only preserve the first 2 values on each line, whereas my original code preserved all the values. A simple change to the find/repl strings should do the trick:

```
) do call jrepl " +([^ ]+)" ";$1" /a /exc 1:29 /f "%%F" /o -
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tail` and `sed` :

```
tail -n +30 file | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \+\([^ ]* \).*/\1;\2/;/^$/{N;/End/d}'
```

`tail` deletes first 29 lines.

`sed` search and capture strings beginning with non-space characters followed by one or more spaces followed with non-space characters followed by one space. Both captured groups are output with a `;` between.

`/^$/{N;/End/d}` removes the `End` line.

To recursively apply the above commands to all .csv files starting from current directory :

```
find . -name "*.csv" -print0 -exec sh -c 'tail -n +30 {} | sed "s/^\([^ ]*\) \+\([^ ]* \).*/\1;\2/;/^$/{N;/End/d}" > {}.new' \;
```

All proccessed files will be suffixed with the `.new` extension.

Comment: Thank you. the file was created but it is empty

Comment: It worked for me with your sample code. It won't work if files have not the same structure. What's the output from the first command with `tail`and `sed` ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this php-script that does the job perfectly:

```
<?php
$base = "BM_BLANK_";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {
  $myfile = fopen($base.$i.".txt", "r") or die("Kann Datei nicht öffnen!");
  $arr = explode(PHP_EOL, substr(strstr(fread($myfile, filesize($base.$i.".txt")),"1200"),12,-8));
  foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new[$key] = explode("  ", $value);
    unset($new[$key][2]);
    unset($new[$key][3]);
    unset($new[$key][4]);
  }
  $newfile = fopen($i.".csv", "w");
  $txt = "";
  foreach($new as $sch => $wert) {
    $txt .= $wert[0].";".$wert[1]."\n";
  }
  fwrite($newfile, $txt);
  fclose($newfile);
  fclose($myfile);
}
?>
```